# ¿Cómo hacer map de un arreglo por grupo en React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Tengo un arreglo con este contenido:

```
const Arr =[
 {idpregunta: '1', fecha: '21/09/2020', pregunta: 'cómo te llamas?', imagen: 'Imagen1'},

 {idpregunta: '2', fecha: '21/09/2020', pregunta: 'qué haces?', imagen: 'Imagen2'},

 {idpregunta: '2', fecha: '21/09/2020', pregunta: 'qué haces?', imagen: 'Imagen3'}
]
```

Como pueden ver, hay 2 elementos con el mismo id, fecha y pregunta.
Lo que quiero hacer es mapear ese arreglo, pero en caso de que haya la misma fecha y pregunta, me agrupe las imágenes en un solo div, de caso contrario, que lo ponga en otro con su respectiva fecha y pregunta, por ejemplo:

```
21/09/2020

Qué haces?

 Imagen2, Imagen 3


21/09/2020

Cómo te llamas?

Imagen1
```

Comment: Hola @Michael Scott Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Es importante que tu pregunta incluya un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Te invito a que revises las recomendaciones en [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: En un solo row de que? de un table? de una matriz? otro? cual es el código del componente que tienes armado para manejar esa info?

Comment: Hice algunas correcciones a la pregunta, espero se me pueda entender mejor y me puedan ayudar, gracias